# how to navigate to child view with NavigationStack without re-intializing?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to navigate:

1. Feature 1: `SelectDepartureArrivalView` -> `CommutingView` -> `ArrivedView`
2. Feature 2: `ScheduleView`

Feature 1 have 3 views. Feature 2 only have 1 view.

My expectation: The view only initialized once.

My actual result: The view initialize on every navigation action. Worse, there are 2 SelectedDepartureArrivalViewModel alive when in `ArrivedView`

The code

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  NavigationStackExample
//
//  Created by Jason Rich Darmawan Onggo Putra on 29/07/23.
//

import SwiftUI

enum Page {
    // Feature 1
    case SelectDepartureArrivalView
    case CommutingView
    case ArrivedView
    
    // Feature 2
    case ScheduleView
}

class SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

struct SelectDepartureArrivalView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel = SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel()) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SelectDepartureArrivalView")
            Button {
                coordinator.path.append(.CommutingView)
            } label: {
                Text("Simulate commuting")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
    }
}

class CommutingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

struct CommutingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CommutingViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: CommutingViewModel = CommutingViewModel()) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("CommutingView")
            Button {
                coordinator.path.append(.ArrivedView)
            } label: {
                Text("Simulate arrival")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
    }
}

class ArrivedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

struct ArrivedView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ArrivedViewModel
    
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    init(viewModel: ArrivedViewModel = ArrivedViewModel()) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ArrivedView")
            Button {
                coordinator.path = .init()
            } label: {
                Text("Simulate exit")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
    }
}

class ScheduleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

struct ScheduleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ScheduleViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ScheduleViewModel = ScheduleViewModel()) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ScheduleView")
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
    }
}

class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [Page]
    
    init(path: [Page] = [Page]()) {
        self.path = path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    init(coordinator: Coordinator = Coordinator()) {
        self._coordinator = StateObject(wrappedValue: coordinator)
        
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    coordinator.path.append(.SelectDepartureArrivalView)
                } label: {
                    Text("simulate selecting departure arrival")
                }
                
                Button {
                    coordinator.path.append(.ScheduleView)
                } label: {
                    Text("simulate navigating to the schedule view")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Page.self) { page in
                switch page {
                case .SelectDepartureArrivalView: SelectDepartureArrivalView()
                case .CommutingView: CommutingView()
                case .ArrivedView: ArrivedView()
                
                case .ScheduleView: ScheduleView()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Root -> `coordinator.path.append(.SelectDepartureArrivalView)`

```
ContentView init(coordinator:)
ContentView appear
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel init()
SelectDepartureArrivalView init(viewModel:)
SelectDepartureArrivalView appear 
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel init()
SelectDepartureArrivalView init(viewModel:)
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel deinit
```

1 ContentView appearing.
1 SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel alive.
1 SelectDepartureArrivalView appearing.

SelectDepartureArrivalView -> `coordinator.path.append(.CommutingView)`

```
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel init()
SelectDepartureArrivalView init(viewModel:)
CommutingViewModel init()
CommutingView init(viewModel:)
CommutingView appear 
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel init()
SelectDepartureArrivalView init(viewModel:)
CommutingViewModel init()
CommutingView init(viewModel:)
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel deinit
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel deinit
CommutingViewModel deinit
SelectDepartureArrivalView disappear
```

1 ContentView appearing.
1 SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel alive.
1 CommutingViewModel alive.
1 CommutingView appearing.

CommutingView -> `coordinator.path.append(.ArrivedView)`

```
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel init()
SelectDepartureArrivalView init(viewModel:)
CommutingViewModel init()
CommutingView init(viewModel:)
ArrivedViewModel init()
ArrivedView init(viewModel:)
ArrivedView appear 
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel init()
SelectDepartureArrivalView init(viewModel:)
CommutingViewModel init()
CommutingView init(viewModel:)
ArrivedViewModel init()
ArrivedView init(viewModel:)
CommutingViewModel deinit
CommutingViewModel deinit
ArrivedViewModel deinit
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel deinit
CommutingView disappear
```

1 ContentView appearing.
2 SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel alive.
1 CommutingViewModel alive.
1 ArrivalViewModel alive.
1 ArrivedView appearing.

ArrivalView -> `coordinator.path = .init()`

```
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel deinit
SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel deinit
CommutingViewModel deinit
ArrivedView disappear
ArrivedViewModel deinit
```

1 ContentView appearing.

Comment: You should never do anything heavy in the `init` of a `View` (like creating objects like this) and should never rely on a `View`'s `init` being called _once_. Also, you should be using `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` where you own the object. Then, the creation of that `@StateObject` is done in an auto closure. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for more information

Comment: @jnpdx thank you for pointing out Demystify SwiftUI. ViewBuilder and Identifiable is very useful. However, `navigationDestination` is the culprit of initializing the ViewModel twice, even with @StateObject. I will recreate the post since the code differ so much.

Comment: You should close this question if it's superseded by the new one